# Duplicating object along curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have an object that i would like to duplicate along a curve. To do that, I have added a Array modifier that duplicates the object and a Curve modifier and selected the appropriate curve object to guide placement of the duplicates. However, selecting none of the axes produces the correct result, which should be the obejcts placed along the curve. What am I doing wrong or missing?

This is an asteroid next to a sun object. Ultimately, I would like to create a bunch of asteroids around the sun. My plan is to duplicate the asteroids many times along the curve and then to randomize their placement, rotation and scale a bit so that the lot looks natural.

For the reference, here's my scene .blend file: [Scene .blend](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AohDmDW98tXLg_BT8YIqR32mn9hhEg?e=8NdQjd)

Comment: Why not just parent the asteroid to an empty at the center point of the orbit? Duplicate, resize and reorient to taste, and then they all will rotate with the empty. If you don't want them to, duplicate the empty and create new parenting relationships. When it comes to planetary orbits, my view is that curves are overkill, since they are capable of making objects change course in all three dimensions, and you don't need that functionality here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your asteroid and:

- Apply its rotation and scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).
- Move it at the same point as the bezier's origin (as it is the center of the scene you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>).
- In its *Curve* modifier choose *Deformation Axis* > *X*.
- If you apply the curve's scale, bring back the vertices radius to one in the *N* panel.

It should work.

Comment: Thank you! Setting it on the same point as the bezier's origin and applying the rotation and scale was what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.7x there was a function called Dupliframe which puts an object where it is and then an instance where it would be in the next frame and so on. If it's a one-time thing I would suggest to go back to 2.79 for this 1 step. If you need to replicate it, or want to stay in 2.8, the animation nodes have a fairly simple setup for that, but they can seem intimidating at first.